# identifying strings which cant be spelt in a list item

Tags: python, regex, parsing

I have a list

```
['mPXSz0qd6j0 youtube ', 'lBz5XJRLHQM youtube ', 'search OpHQOO-DwlQ ', 
'sachin 47427243 ', 'alex smith ', 'birthday JEaM8Lg9oK4 ', 
'nebula  8x41n9thAU8 ', 'chuck norris  ', 
'searcher O6tUtqPcHDw ', 'graham wXqsg59z7m0 ', 'queries K70QnTfGjoM ']
```

Is there some way to identify the strings which can't be spelt in the list item and remove them?

Comment: as you can see the strings like mPXSz0qd6j0, lBz5XJRLHQM which cant be spelled.

Comment: Can I think the rules like if the word with mixed letter and number need be cleaned?

Comment: +1 for procedure @p.s.w.g

Comment: @BMW in this case may be yes. But what if there is some string like "XhIjkHe"

Comment: you need to check if this words are in dictionary :D

Comment: yes. for that do I need to use some kind of NLP library? or will some regular expression do?

Comment: Ok, then add one more rule: if the word with mixed uppercase and lowercase letters(not the first letter) or numbers, then this word will be removed. How about this?

Comment: yes. that might do. let me try it

Comment: @BMW depends on whether `fasdfhlerkfhe` is considered good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use, e.g. [PyEnchant](http://pythonhosted.org/pyenchant/api/enchant.html) for basic dictionary checking and [NLTK](http://nltk.org/) to take minor spelling issues into account, like this:

```
import enchant
import nltk

spell_dict = enchant.Dict('en_US')  # or whatever language supported

def get_distance_limit(w):
    ''' 
    The word is considered good 
    if it's no further from a known word than this limit.
    '''
    return len(w)/5 + 2  # just for example, allowing around 1 typo per 5 chars.

def check_word(word):
    if spell_dict.check(word):
        return True  # a known dictionary word

    # try similar words
    max_dist = get_distance_limit(word)
    for suggestion in spell_dict.suggest(word):
        if nltk.edit_distance(suggestion, word) < max_dist:
            return True

    return False
```

Add a case normalisation and a filter for digits and you'll get a pretty good heuristics.

Comment: Although this seems like a good way to proceed. This library doesnt check for nouns. For example, alex is not a word according to spell check.

Comment: @scu but `Alex` is a word, so it will be returned as an option by `spell_dict.suggest()`, and the distance is minimal.

Comment: How about ravi. I know this isn't a common name among the people in US. It's a common Indian Name. I have tried using en_IN locale. It doesn't suggest anything near to it.

Comment: @scu for me it suggests `['Ravi', 'rave', 'Rafi', 'Raven']` in `en_US` locale. I even tried `sasha` which is a diminutive form of `Alexander` in Russian, with great success :)

Comment: (But, of course, nothing guarantees from some false negatives, since the definition of a legitimate word is a bit vague)

Comment: Ok. Anyway this answer seems to solve most of the issues I had. Accepting it. Thanks a ton :)

Answer (score 0):

It is entirely possible to compare your list members to words that you don't believe to be valid for your input.

This can be done in many ways, partially depending on your definition of "properly spelled" and what you end up using for a comparison list.  If you decide that numbers preclude an entry from being valid, or underscores, or mixed case, you could test for regex matching.

Post regex, you would have to decide what a valid character to split on should be.  Is it spaces (are you willing to break on 'ad hoc' ('ad' is an abbreviation, 'hoc' is not a word))?  Is it hyphens (this will break on hyphenated last names)?

With these above criteria decided, it's just a decision of what word, proper name, and common slang list to use and a list comprehension:

```
word_list[:] = [term for term in word_list if passes_my_membership_criteria(term)]
```

where passes_my_membership_criteria() is a function that contains the rules for staying in the list of words, returning False for things that you've decided are not valid.